# What is the difference between Null and Blank in django Model

Tags: django, django-models

```
status = models.IntegerField(choices=list(CAMPAIGN_STATUS), default=CAMPAIGN_STATUS.PAUSE,
          verbose_name=_("status"), blank=True, null=True)
```

What is the difference in blank=True, null=True ?

Comment: [Why are Stack Overflow users more passionate about Stack Overflow than helping people?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315018/1324033)

Comment: 1. Please don't blame your lack of research on me, its literally the first result on google. and 2. Believe me, If i cared about reputation as much as you think I do it would be *a lot* higher than it is.

Comment: it is my very first post in stack overflow you have to guide me not to degrade me

Comment: No I don't, New users have to click a checkbox at the bottom of the How to Ask page indicating that they understand what they just read, before they can post their first question. So you will have already stated that you understand how to ask a valid question. If you wish to disagree further, I invite you to ask a question on [meta]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`blank=True` is about validation, `True` means that field is not required. `null=True` allows you to save a null value.
Also you are not always need to define both of them when you want optional field. String value, like a `CharField` or a `TextField` are better be stored in an empty string, so you should use only `blank=True`.
In your case, with not required `IntegerField` you should use both `blank` and `null`
[here the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/)

Comment: Thanks you so Much ! your answer is really helpful for me